# Is it possible in C# to override literals?

Tags: c#, arrays, literals

Is there any way possible in C# to override or create new literals? Overriding operators is possible:

```cs
class DynamicList<T> : DynamicCollection
{
  //...
  
  public static DynamicList operator+ (DynamicList l1, DynamicList l2)
  {
    return l1.Clone().Concat(l2);
  }

  //...
}

DynamicList<int> list1 = new DynamicList<int> (0, 1, 2);
DynamicList<int> list2 = new DynamicList<int> (3, 4, 5, 6);
// DynamicList<int> list3 = list1.Clone().Concat(list2);
DynamicList<int> list3 = list1 + list2;
```

A workaround for strings and primitive types exists by using implicit operators:

```cs
class RegExp
{
  //...

  public static implicit operator RegExp (String s)
  {
    return new RegExp (s);
  }

  //...
}

//RegExp email = new RegExp (...);
RegExp email = "([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9.]{3,20})@([A-Za-z0-9\\-\\_]{3,20})\\.([a-z0-9]{3-12}(\\.[a-z0-9]{3-12})*)";
```

Is it possible to repurpose array literals to achieve something of this sort:

```cs
class DynamicList<T> : DynamicCollection
{
  //...
}

// DynamicList<int> list = new DynamicList<int> (0, 1, 2);
DynamicList<int> list = {0, 1, 2};
```

Comment: Most likely `var list = new DynamicList<int> { 1, 2, 3 };` You're describing a [*Collection Initializer*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers).

Comment: You can do `DynamicList<int> x = new[]{0, 1, 2}` but not using the expression you show above since that is syntactic sugar.

Comment: With a collection initializer (that is, a valid `Add` method and `IEnumerable` implementation) the statement can become `DynamicList<int> list = new() { 0, 1, 2 }` which is as close to your intended syntax as you can get.

Comment: Incidentally, I would recommend against having a constructor that takes a `params T[]` as you now appear to do (assuming the `new DynamicList<int> (0, 1, 2)` is what you currently use), as the hidden and likely unnecessary cost of array allocation is not immediately obvious. If the constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, you can initialize it with any collection (and if you have a particularly efficient way of treating arrays, for example because you can simply copy the array into your own, you can still handle that with type checks).

Comment: @JeroenMostert You could always have both constructors, with the `params` constructor calling the `IEnumerable` constructor.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: that doesn't resolve my main beef with `params` constructors, in that the hidden allocation overhead is often not worth it, since the readability improvements are minimal and they can actually make it ambiguous which constructor ends up being called. Every instantiation of a `DynamicList` that way also creates a garbage array on the sly without this being very clear in the source. If the caller doesn't already have an array they want to pass (which the `IEnumerable` would handle), they should probably prefer a collection initializer.

Comment: If `DynamicList` has an `Add` function then `new DynamicList<int> { 1, 2, 3 }` should work